# Need for Speed Undercover Screenshots

Tags: need-for-speed-undercover

When I take screenshots using the in-game "Photo Mode," a message says they are uploaded to NeedForSpeed.com.  However, browsing that website, I can't find them anywhere.  Apparently, other people had the same issue.  However, every "fix" I've found references a page that either never loads, or redirects me to NeedForSpeed.com.

Where do the screenshots end up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshots *used* to end up on a website called "MyNFS". In fact, as near as I can tell, the servers are still up and receiving screenshots. But the developers at one point took the website down to redesign it and, well, forgot to put it back up. [It's been confirmed by a rep that it's not coming back](http://www.nextgenupdate.com/forums/general-discussion/332121-need-speed-undercover-photo-mode.html) (no doubt it was lost in the shuffle to the next Need for Speed.)

You can download a mod that removes the text from Photo Mode, allowing you to snap screenshots with PrntScrn ([scroll down to the end of this list](http://www.nfsplanet.de/nfsuc_files.php?lang=eng)). Alternately, if you don't want to mess around with mods, you can hit Enter in Photo Mode and then quickly hit PrntScrn before the "Connecting to EA Nation" dialog box appears.